# TRIM values after pattern

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have a table of urls that are not valid.

I need to pull a query with only valid urls but also clean up any urls that I can.

Such as, trimming up any sting after `.com`

Requirements:
•   Web address must be in a URL format (`http://abc.xxx` , `http://www.abc.xxx` or `www.abc.xxx`)

```
 select url,
 case
 when regexp_like(r.url, '^(http(s)*://)*[a-z0-9.-]+$')
 then r.url
 else null 
 end webAddress2
 from url r
```

URL table:

```
id  URL  
 1  http://www.a.com/NSLIJ/lij
 2  G.F@xx.com
 3  /www.smithtowncenter.com
 4  www.b.com
 5  http://b.com
 6  http://www.b.com
```

I've used `regexp_like` but it's not quite correct and doesn't `trim`

Any help would be appreciated.

Query results (should look like)

```
 id  URL                             newURL
 1  http://www.a.com/NSLIJ/lij     http://www.a.com (trimmed off `/NSLIJ/lij`
 2  G.F@xx.com
 3  /www.smithtowncenter.com         www.smithtowncenter.com (trimmed off `/`)
 4  www.b.com                        www.b.com
 5  http://.b.com                    http://.b.com
 6  http://www.b.com                 http://www.b.com
```

Comment: `http://.b.com` is not a valid url

Comment: @David True, edit made.

Comment: there is the TRIM function, no?

Comment: Are there any other protocols you want to allow like https or ftp;.  Are alternative ports ok like: domain.com:8080.  What about credentials like user:pass@domain.com.  How about ip addresses like: http://142.251.33.78.  You need to use regexp_substr to return the portion of the string that matches your regex.  To write the regex you need to know exactly what it is supposed to match.

Comment: Try `select url,
 case
 when regexp_like(r.url, '^(https?://)?[a-z0-9.-]+$')
 then r.url
 else  regexp_replace(r.url, '((https?://|www\.)[a-z0-9.-]+)|.', '\2')
 end webAddress2
 from url r`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the regexp `^(http(s)?://)?[a-z0-9]+(\.[a-z0-9]+)+(/[a-zA-Z]+)*?$` to find correct matches.

For example:

```
select t.*,
  case when regexp_like(url, '^(http(s)?://)?[a-z0-9]+(\.[a-z0-9]+)+(/[a-zA-Z]+)*?$') 
  then 'valid' else 'invalid' end as chk
from t;
```

Result:

```
 ID  URL                         CHK     
 --- --------------------------- ------- 
 1   http://www.a.com/NSLIJ/lij  valid   
 2   G.F@xx.com                  invalid 
 3   /www.smithtowncenter.com    invalid 
 4   www.b.com                   valid   
 5   http://b.com                valid   
 6   http://www.b.com            valid
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=8a12b18c4d7e8e7ad95b85399826a4b0).